Prometheus Endpoint Not Working with springboot application. Getting 404 error page
Prometheus Endpoint Not Working with springboot application. Getting 404 error page.
I've added the dependency according to the ducomantaion
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
  <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
</dependency>

And changed the yml file to:
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
     base-path: /   
     exposure:
        include: prometheus
      

If I go to http://localhost:9083/actuator
I'm getting this :

As you can see, there is no prometheus
In http://localhost:9083/actuator/prometheus
I'm getting this error:

I've tried everything that is written in those answers:
Getting "Whitelabel Error Page" when opening "/actuator/mappings"
Unable to access Spring Boot Actuator "/actuator" endpoint
Spring Boot /actuator returns 404 not found
Noting seems to be working, any idea?

Base path is set to /, so path should be /prometheus, and health should be /health.

After much research and many attempts to solve the problem, I realized that because I already have this definition spring.config.location set in VM arguments, prometheus can not run.  It expects the spring settings to be read and it blocks it.
I've changed it from spring.config.location to spring.config.additional-location.
now it is working!

Only the health endpoint are exposed through HTTP by default.
You must expose prometheus as well:
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health,prometheus

or with yaml
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: health,prometheus

Please read more in the official documentation:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#actuator.endpoints.exposing

Hi, I've config my yml as :
management:
endpoints:
web:
exposure:
include: prometheus
base-path: /
The yml is as I wrote in my question. Why is it wrong?

Try to remove base-path this is not necessary

Thank you for your reply. it is not working, getting the same error.

It works if I use application.properties but not when I use application.yaml

Check your spring version. I'd followed the various guides and issues, nothing worked for me until I updated from 3.1.4 --> 3.1.6.
Once that was done, the bare minimum configuration as described by https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-prometheus  just worked.
